# A series $s_n$ converges $\iff$ $s_{n_k}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was wondering if this is true:

> A series $s_n =\sum a_i$ converges if and only if there exist $n_k$ such as $ s_{n_k} $ converges.

Especially the right-to-left way:

> If there exists $n_k$ such as $s_{n_k}$ converges then the series $s_n$ converges.

The last assertion (theorem) is supposed to be based on this reasoning:

Let $n_k' \in \mathbb N ^ {\mathbb N}$.

By assumption we have: $|s_{n_k} - s| < \epsilon /2$ for every $n\geq N$ ($s$ being the sum of $s_n$).

Let $k\in \mathbb N, k \geq N$.

Suppose, without loss of generality, that $n_k < n_k '$.

The reasoning is based on  the fact that: $|s_{n_k} - s_{n_k'}|=  a_{n_k+1} + ... + a_{n_k'} < \epsilon /2$

There is the point that makes me think that the theorem is incorrect: the general term of the series does not necessarily have to converge to $0$.

So the theorem is not true ?

Comment: The fact that the series has at least one [Accumulation Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulation_point) does not imply that the series is convergent.

Comment: Consider the series $\sum (-1)^n$. It has a subsequence of partial sums that is identically $0$ and another subsequence that is identically $1$

Comment: So depending on where we put the parenthesis in the sum, the result of the sum changes. That means that not only commutativity is violated at $\infty$ (cf. permutations) but also associativity . Interesting

Comment: The existence of a single convergent subsequence is not enough. A sequence converges iff ALL subsequences converge.

Comment: The theorem is true if the terms are  either all positive or all negative though, because then the series is monotone.

Comment: @Alan your enrichment of "my" theorem seems very interesting but I fail to understand why it would be true

Comment: If it's monotonic and any subsequence converges,  then any other subsequence will also have to converge, you can simply squeeze the terms  of the new subsequence intertwined in the old ones.

Comment: "That means that not only commutativity is violated at $\infty$  (cf. permutations) but also associativity".  No...  I would say: All of the useful properties of convergent series may fail for divergent series.

Answer (score 1):

Try thinking about the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n$ with $a_n$ defined as

$$
a_n = \begin{cases}
  1/n^2,  & n \text{ is even} \\
  1-\frac{1}{(n-1)^2}, & n \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$

Why would this disprove your claim?

Comment: The $s_{n_k}$ terms are still adding all the $a_i$ terms up to it

Comment: My apologies. Do you see how your assertion may not work given my revised sequence?

Comment: So you would have $s_n$ not converging while $s_{n_k}$ converging ?

Comment: The subsequence $s_{2k}$ $\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{36}+\ldots \right)$ converges, but what about the subsequence $s_{2k+1}$? If a sequence has a divergent subsequence, the sequence can't converge. Andrew's example works as well.

Comment: $s_{2k}$ does include $a_1 =1$ I think you are having a confusing. Example $s_2 = a_1 + a_2$

Comment: That's not $s_{2k}$.   $s_{2k}$ isn't just adding the even terms of $a_n$, it's adding all the terms from $a_1$ through $a_2k$